# Laravel - Efficient Way to Query Monthly Data per Category

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm working on a project that requires me to generate a report similar to this:

```
Category        Total   Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Category 1      97      10  10  10  10  10  5   10  10  7   5   5   5
Category 2      120     10  10  10  10  10  10  20  10  5   5   10  10
Category 3      5       0   0   0   3   0   2   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

This report needs to be generated from data similar to this:

```
id      category_id     type    year    month       amount
----------------------------------------------------------
1       1               16      2016    1           4
2       1               23      2016    1           6
3       1               76      2016    2           3
4       1               27      2016    2           3
5       1               18      2016    2           4
```

In the report, each month's number is simply the sum of the `amount` for that particular category, year, and month. I can do this just fine by querying the database for each month and for each category, but this type of approach doesn't scale very well if I need to generate a report with about a hundred categories because it would take over 1,200 queries (100 categories X 12 months)!

Any suggestions of how to make this more efficient?

Thanks!

Comment: Yep. A decent book or tutorial should help with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is grouping by two columns.I added the necessary code to format the results as you want.

```
Item::where('year', $year)
        ->groupBy('month', 'category_id')
        ->selectRaw('sum(amount) as sum, month, category_id')
        ->orderBy('category_id')
        ->orderBy('month')
        ->get()
        ->groupBy('category_id')
        ->map(function($item){
                $item = $item->pluck('sum', 'month');
                $item['total'] = $item->sum();
                return $item;
            });
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! I already knew I could have grouped my results together, but the mapping part at the end was what I was hoping someone could provide. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
Category::where('year', 2016)
  ->select('month', 'year', DB::raw('SUM(amount) as amountTotal'))
  ->groupBy('month', 'year')
  ->get();
```